# JQuery on radio button click Uncaught throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which when you click / check a specific radio button, it shows or hides some elements.  This function also needs to run on page load in case MVC validation comes back with an error on post.  The problem is I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` on page load, and although the code does work, it breaks all of the code below it in the scripts section. I'm coming to the conclusion that I am not checking which radio button is selected properly here: `if ($element.attr('class').indexOf('update-type-check-current') !== -1)`.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        clickFunc($(this));
    });
    clickFunc($('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type=radio]:checked'));
});

function clickFunc($element) {
    var currentEmployee = $('.current-employee');
    if ($element.attr('class').indexOf('update-type-check-current') !== -1) {
        currentEmployee.show();
    }
    else {
        currentEmployee.hide();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="UpdateType">New or Current?</label>
    <div class="col-md-10" id="CurrentEmployeeRB">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="btn btn-primary update-type-check-new" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please select whether the employee is new or current." id="UpdateType" name="UpdateType" type="radio" value="New"> New
        </label>
        <br>
        <label class="radio-inline">
            <input class="btn btn-secondary update-type-check-current" id="UpdateType" name="UpdateType" type="radio" value="Current"> Current
        </label>
        <br>
        <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="UpdateType" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Razor:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UpdateType, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10" id="CurrentEmployeeRB">
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UpdateType, "New", new { @class = "btn btn-primary update-type-check-new" }) New
        </label>
        <br />
        <label class="radio-inline">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.UpdateType, "Current", new { @class = "btn btn-secondary update-type-check-current" }) Current
        </label>
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UpdateType, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a different way I should be doing this? I'm just getting into learning JQuery and I'm not finding any working alternatives so far through searching.

Comment: What is it your trying to achieve?

Comment: Check again for this line: `clickFunc($('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type=radio]:checked'))`. That line requires a radio button which checked. But there were no radio buttons which checked by default.

Comment: You don't have any class as current-employee in your HTML

Comment: Instead of `indexOf` you should use `hasClass`...

Comment: @HappyCoding this fixed the error that came up, although it makes the function not run again after the post. I don't necessarily want a default radio button checked... is there a way around this?

Comment: @justiceorjustus That line would be run automatically when reloading page. It calls `clickFunc` function with undefined parameter. So, because `$element` is undefined, then it doesn't contain property `indexOf` as the error you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the line at ready

```
clickFunc($('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type=radio]:checked'));
```

with

```
if($('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type=radio]:checked').length >= 1) {
   clickFunc($('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type=radio]:checked'));
}
```

Comment: Perfect! You got to it first. Definitely helped me understand logically what was going on here a lot, too!

Comment: Also like @eisbehr suggested you should check with hasClass, works better in your case.

Comment: Bad idea. The OP said that he needn't a checked radio button by default. That mean, the condition in the `if` statement would never true. Also, it will check one times after page load, not everytimes when checking the radio button.

Comment: He doesn't need one checked by default but he needs to check if one is, depending on the parameters. Also yes this condition checks only on page load because that's when the code broke.

Comment: @yomisimie I changed that, as well.

Comment: @HappyCoding What would the alternative be? It seems to work for what I need.

Comment: I mean the solution looks like adding `//` before the line. LoL. ok stop.

Comment: Yes, but he needs the line like he says, he needs checking on page load:
`I have a form which when you click / check a specific radio button, it shows or hides some elements. This function also needs to run on page load in case MVC validation comes back with an error on post.`

Comment: @yomisimie is correct. it seems silly to not have a default radio button checked, which would lose the need for this, but I do want to force the user to make a choice rather than submit with default.

Answer (score 1):

Don't search with `indexOf`, use `hasClass`. Your code fails if no element was returned by selector otherwise.

```
function clickFunc($element) {
    var currentEmployee = $('.current-employee');

    if( $element.hasClass('update-type-check-current') ) {
        currentEmployee.show();
    }
    else {
        currentEmployee.hide();
    }
}
```

Just a tip: you can use `toggle` for the same task too:

```
function clickFunc($element) {
    $('.current-employee').toggle($element.hasClass('update-type-check-current'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly change `$('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type=radio]:checked')` to `$('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type="radio"]:checked')` and initially since after document loads no radio button is checked `$element` doesn't contain anything and thus you get that error so place you logic inside an `if statement` as

```
if($element.length != 0) {}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
        clickFunc($(this));
    });
    clickFunc($('#CurrentEmployeeRB input[type="radio"]:checked'));
});

function clickFunc($element) {
    if($element.length != 0) {
    var currentEmployee = $('.current-employee');
    console.log($element);
    if ($element.attr('class').indexOf('update-type-check-current') !== -1) {
        currentEmployee.show();
    }
    else {
        currentEmployee.hide();
    }
      }
}
```